# Streaming Audio from server to Android App

Tags: android, heroku, audio-streaming

I am kind of stuck on my app design and wondering, if some of you experts, could point me in the right direction.

I am working an Android App that shows how to pronounce different English words.
When user clicks on a play button next to a word, corresponding audio file (prerecorded wav file) is played with Android media player.   I have 2000 words and corresponding wav files (each file is between 1 to 2 seconds).

But the problem is, I can’t pack all 2000 audio files into APP, as it will make APP too big.  I am wondering, what is the best way of having the audio files on the server somewhere, and when user clicks play button next to a word, my APP plays from server. Are there any other ways of doing this?

Do I need streaming server for this (it’s not live stream), if so would you please let me know some that host? Can I use Heroku?

Thanks for help
Srini

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a streaming server for that. A simple web pages server will do the job. Just put all your files in (maybe via ftp) to the server in a directory that you now exactly. From there, you can use the MediaPlayer class of android to play those sounds in streaming with the appropriate link to the file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know.